# Как правильно setState написать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается изменить значение инпута. Как правильно это сделать?

Что есть на данный момент.

State:

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                objects: {
                    name: '',
                    mass: [
                        {
                            img: '',
                            count: '1', // Это первый инпут
                            countMass: '2' // Это состояние второго инпута
                        },
                        {
                            img: '',
                            count: '1', // Это первый инпут
                            countMass: '2' // Это состояние второго инпута
                        },
                };
            };

            this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
          }
```

JSX:

```
{this.mass.map((variant, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>
            <Input name={"count" + index} onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={variant.count} />
            <Input name={"countMass" + index} onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={variant.mass}/>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Функция:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    let objects = {...this.state.objects}
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        objects: {
            ...objects,
            mass: [
                {[name]: value}
            ]
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: вы сами усложняете свою работу когда используете this.setState

Comment: А как надо? Делал по https://ru.react.js.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в `name` инпута хранится значение ключа + индекс `name={"count" + index}`, поэтому и в обработчике `{[name]: value}` это уже совсем другое

И использовать индекс в качестве ключа не очень [рекомендуется](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

```
mass: [
   {[name]: value}
]
```

Вот эта строчка делает не то что вы хотите: она перезапишет массив в стейте оставив один элемент

Нужно, сделать как-то так:

```
{this.mass.map((variant, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={variant.id}>
            <Input name={"count-" + index} data-id={variant.id} onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={variant.count} />
            <Input name={"countMass-" + index} data-id={variant.id} onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={variant.mass}/>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Добавить в стейте `id` для элементов массива

```
mass: [
  {
    id: "1", // нужно число
    img: '',
    count: '',
    countMass: ''
  },
  // ...
]
```

И в обработчике уже правильно обновлять стейте

```
  handleInputChange({target}) {
    const objects = {...this.state.objects}
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name.split('-')[0];
    const id = target.getAttribute('data-id');

    // Так безопасней искать объект, нежели по индексу
    const changedIndex = objects.mass.findIndex(el => el.id === id);
    const changedEl = objects.mass[changedIndex];
    changedEl[name] = value;

    this.setState({
      objects: {
        ...objects,
        mass: [
          ...objects.mass.slice(0, changedIndex),
          changedEl,
          ...objects.mass.slice(changedIndex + 1),
        ]
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94290/discussion-on-answer-by-thisman---setstate-).